# Drawing Parametric Curve with Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Can anyone help me what equation can draw this in turtle python? I try many way but it all still triangle or circle output

[image]

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: A very similar question has been asked already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936731/spirograph-turtle-python

However, this tutorial looks more sophisticated than the answers there: https://www.101computing.net/python-turtle-spirograph/

Comment: Sorry, actually I came across from many topic and trying but I cant find any finer equation that turtle can draw like that

Comment: Have you made any attempt to implement this? It would be helpful if you posted your code. It almost looks like you're commissioning people to write a very specific algorithm for free.

Comment: Wait I not that meant, I just want to find the equation to solve the problem but not the code

Comment: Perhaps you should ask here then https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Decompose it into a simple shape. What if you draw a triangle and rotate it? Please post your attempts so the question is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

My initial impression is that this drawing is composed of only straight lines and any curves seen in the image are purely in the eye of the observer.  To convince myself of this, I first wrote a six line turtle program to generate this figure using only turtle's `forward` and `left` methods:

[image]

Then I thought about how to deform my drawing to look more like the example you provided.  Since it's longest at the top and sides, and shortest between, I decided to used `sin` and `cos` from the math library to increase the line lengths at the axis positions (where either `sin` or `cos` are at a maximum.)  This approach ended up drawing the following:

[image]

This only added three lines to my program (including `import` for `sin` and `cos`, etc.)  It's not perfect, but it convinces me that this might just be a sequence of straight lines with no actual parametric curve.